# Split a big collection into smaller ones

Tags: scala

Let's say I have this:

```
val list = Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

I would like to transform it into this

```
Seq[Seq[Int]]
```

Except that the inner Seq should be of size 2 max, so the final output is something like this

```
Seq(Seq(1,2), Seq(3,4), Seq(5,6), Seq(7))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `grouped` method, which returns an `Iterator`. You can then call `toSeq` or `toList` on the `Iterator`.

```
scala> list.grouped(2).toSeq
res14: Seq[Seq[Int]] = Stream(List(1, 2), ?)
```